# Use sed or awk to find string and modify text following within xml document

Tags: xml, macos, bash, sed

I am attempting to manipulate an Adobe Reader plist file on OS X to stop auto update checking.
This needs to be scripting so I can affect the change on 700+ Macs.

I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
plutil -convert xml1 /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.Reader.plist
```

to convert the file for text editing.

I found this elsewhere for multi-line search and replace:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/<h2.*</h2>/No title here/g;p;}' sample.php > sample-edited.php;
```

The source file has repetitions of similar data, so I need to find the occurrence after the entry **CheckForUpdatesAtStartup**

Here is a portion of the file:

```
<key>AutoUriDetect</key>
                    <array>
                            <integer>0</integer>
                            <true/>
                    </array>
                    <key>CheckForUpdatesAtStartup</key>
                    <array>
                            <integer>0</integer>
                            <true/>
                    </array>
                    <key>CheckGPUAtStartup</key>
                    <array>
                            <integer>0</integer>
                            <false/>
                    </array>
```

So I need to replace the **true** to **false** for the **CheckForUpdatesAtStartup** array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk > outfile '/CheckForUpdatesAtStartup/, /<(true|false)\/>/ {
  sub(/true/, "false")
  }1' infile
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dimitre. This is perfect as the change is pinpoint and does not affect the other keys. This is powerful scripting in being able to manipulate plists in the OS X world.